# calling a function and its arguments from a table in q

Tags: kdb

I am trying to call a function and its arguments from a table. So I call the function by:

```
(first exec function from table where id=jobId)
```

In this example I get: +

Then I call the arguments as:

```
[first exec args from table where id=jobId]
```

and I get as an example [2 2]

Running the two lines after each other as:

```
`(first exec func from table where id=jobId)[first exec args from .table where id=jobId]`
```

Will give me: +[2 2]

But I need: +[2;2].

I am reading this statement from the documentations but I could not quite implement.

"
    Arguments to the functional form of exec (?[;;;]) must be passed in parsed form and, depending upon the desired results, in a particular data structure. "

I tried to convert the passing of the arguments part into a functional call like this:

`?[table;jobId=id;args;()]`

Answer (score 5):

To cover the general case of functions with single inputs, multiple inputs etc you'd need something like:

```
q)t:([]func:({x+1};floor;{x+y};first;{x+100});args:(12;1.5;2 2;"abc";`foo))

q)t
func    args
-------------
{x+1}   12
_:      1.5
{x+y}   2 2
*:      "abc"
{x+100} `foo

q)update res:{.[x;(),y;@[x;y;]`$]}'[func;args] from t
func    args  res
-------------------
{x+1}   12    13
_:      1.5   1
{x+y}   2 2   4
*:      "abc" "a"
{x+100} `foo  `type
```

Answer (score 4):

To call your function and arguments from a table, you can use a `.` apply, like so:

```
    q)table:([] function:+;args:enlist 2 2;id:1)

    q)table
    function args id
    ----------------
    +        2 2  1
    q)exec .[first function;first args] from table where id=1
    4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this will only execute first row matching the condition(id=1). If there are many rows matching the condition then those will be skipped.

Comment: This works, but how can I represent that in functional format ?[;;;]

Comment: You can use the functional exec of the form: ``?[`table;enlist(=;`id;jobId);();(.;(first;`function);(first;`args))]``

Comment: @kevbuntu why does it need to be in functional format?

Comment: It does not have to be in functional format. I just like to understand in that format too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to execute function on arguments then you could directly do that inside select/exec statement.

```
q) exec function .' args from table where id=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that your table looks something like this

```
q)show table:([] function:(+;*;{x+2*y}); args:(2 2;9 7;1 3); id:0 1 2)
function args id
----------------
+        2 2  0
*        9 7  1
{x+2*y}  1 3  2
```

When you have your function and arguments you can apply using [.(apply)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply):

```
q)jobId:1
q)(first exec function from table where id=jobId) . first exec args from table where id=jobId
63
```

You can simplify the query above to exec only once if you use the ['(each-both)](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both) adverb:

```
q)first exec function .' args from table where id=1
63
```

And if you drop the where clause above you can get the result off applying each function to each of its arguments:

```
q)update result:function .' args from table
function args id result
-----------------------
+        2 2  0  4
*        9 7  1  63
{x+2*y}  1 3  2  7
```